# erro na utilização de pacotes instalados via npm com -g

Tags: node.js, windows, typescript, angular, windows-10

instalei `npm install typescript -g` e `npm install @angular/cli -g` e não estou com acesso a `tsc` e `ng`.

```
'ng' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

'tsc' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.
```

os arquivos `ng.cmd` e `tsc.cmd` estão dentro desta pasta

```
C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

variaveis de ambiente 
Path

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs

C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Roaming\nvm
```

NODE_PATH:

```
C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

NVM_HOME:

```
C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Roaming\nvm
```

NVM_SYMLINK:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

pasta do node instalado:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

windows 10 Home

node: v8.10.0

npm: 5.6.0

> Solução
>
> Obrigado a todos que responderam, depois de alguns ajustes eu acabei
>   conseguindo corrigir.
>
> O nome da varial `Path` para `PATH`.
>
> Em seguida adicione o caminho `C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Roaming\npm`.
>
> reiniciei e voltou a funcionar os comandos tsc e ng

Comment: Qual o erro que deu na instalação ?

Comment: durante a instalação não deu erro, o erro da na execução dos comandos `tsc` e `ng`

Comment: Chegou a reiniciar a maquina depois da instalação ?

Comment: já reiniciei até tentei reinstalar

Answer (score 3):

No Windows, adicione nas variáveis de ambiente, adicionando no variável PATH o valor abaixo:

```
%AppData%\npm;
```

Salve, feche o terminal `cmd` ou `cmder` ou PowerShell, e tente rodar o comando `ng` novamente.

Talvez tenha que logar no Windows novamente.

Informe se deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Está usando o CMD padrão do Windows ou o Power Shell? As vezes usar o [cmder](http://cmder.net/) ou mesmo o git bash resolve... Ou talvez usar o terminal do [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

Comment: Já testei o CMD, Power Shell, git bash e terminal VSCode e mesmo assim continuei com este problema